# Angular before two-way data binding event

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

Is there an event that fires before two-way data binding.
I have this

```
<input (change)="updateANN()" [(ngModel)]="annModel.neuronsPerLayer" type="number" [formControl]="numOfNeurons" required>
```

I want something like this

```
<input (beforeChange)="myFunction()"  (change)="updateANN()" [(ngModel)]="annModel.neuronsPerLayer" type="number" [formControl]="numOfNeurons" required>
```

and in component.ts

```
myFunction():boolean
{
     let ind = true;
     /* ... */
     return ind;
}
```

if `myFunction` return `True` continue with data binding, otherwise don't change value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use keydown or keypress event, which fires off before change.

```
(keypress)="myFunction($event)"

myFunction(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

A working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gznkiy

Answer (score 0):

There is an event before change actually happens and it's called `(ngModelChanges)="someFunc()"` but after it finishes, the value will be changed no matter what

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution as for conditional binding is to use getter and setter:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model['x']" required>
```

**Controller:**

```
model = {
  x_value: null,

  get x() { 
    return this.x_value;
  },

  set x(newValue) { 
    this.x_value = newValue;
    if (condition) {
      this.x_value = default_value;
    }
  },
}
```

Or just use **ngModelChange**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model.x"(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" required>
```

**Controller:**

```
  onChange(newValue) {
      this.model['x'] = newValue;
      if (!newValue) {
        this.model['x'] = default_value;
      }
    }
```